Generating Equal Amplitude Superposition States from Another Equal Amplitude Superposition State
Can we prepare a state regarding a transformation in quantum computing that seems to generate another equal amplitude superposition state when applying a Hadamard gate?
Specifically, I observed that starting with an equal complex amplitude superposition of all possible state and applying a Hadamard gate resulted in another equal amplitude superposition state with different phases.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1}a_{x}\left|x\right>\xrightarrow{\mathbb H^{\otimes n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1}b_{y}\left|y\right>$$
I would like to discuss how can we prepare the initial state and explore its potential applications and implications for quantum algorithms.

@forky40 , I've tested my state up to n=8 (N = 256). Since my PC is somewhat outdated, it can't simulate more than that. However, I have a doubt; maybe for some n, it may fail to give the required equal superposition. I'd like to know the benefits of such a state, as someone might be looking for this kind of state for a specific purpose. That's my intention.

a and b are just global phases, since it's the same term for all x. This means the left term and the right term are both an equal superposition of all basis states on n qubits. Applying Hadamard gates to each qubit in such a state yields an all-zero state, so the equality doesn't hold.

A state that is an equal superposition of all basis states is a well-known thing in quantum algorithms - Deutsch-Jozsa and Grover are just two examples that come to mind - but it's also not challenging to prepare, just apply Hadamards to an all-zero basis state.

@MariiaMykhailova, I am so sorry my mistake when writing the equations a and b are not global phases, for each components they have their own phases

Does $a_i=a_j$, or $b_i=b_j$ for every $i,j$?

Are you looking to characterize all states with this property, or only to have a meaningful list of examples?

@MarkSpinelli , not for every i and j but for some might be.

@TristanNemoz, I am looking for the potential advantage of the operation,For instance in Grover, we start by hadamarding the the zero state and mark the solution and when we perform Hadamard again we got the zero amplitude is higher than the others, and Grover's mark except the Zero and Hadamard for the third time to raise the amplitude of the marked solution, but in here we will not have a superior amplitude after the marking of the solution since every state has equal amplitude, I want to get the idea if there is a chance to exploit this bro.

TL;DR
Yes, it is actually very simple to prepare a state that has the wanted property. Namely, $$|i\rangle^{\otimes n} = S^{\otimes n} H^{\otimes n} |0\rangle^{\otimes n}$$ with $|i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle$.
Why it works
$|i\rangle^{\otimes n}$ is of the form:
$$|i\rangle^{\otimes n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2^n}} \sum_{x = 0}^{2^n - 1}a_x |x\rangle$$
with $a_x = i^{f(x)}$ where $f(x)$ denotes the number of $1$s in the binary representation of $x$.
Notice that $H |i\rangle \propto |-i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle - i|1\rangle)$ (ignoring the global phase) and hence:
$$H^{\otimes n}|i\rangle^{\otimes n} \propto |-i\rangle^{\otimes n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2^n}} \sum_{x = 0}^{2^n - 1}b_y |y\rangle $$
with $b_y = (-i)^{f(y)}$.
Some additional remarks
Since, $H$ is self-inverse you could alternatively start with $|-i\rangle^{\otimes n}$. (or in fact, any combination of $|i\rangle$ and $|-i\rangle$ states)
For the state preparation, I chose $|i\rangle = SH|0\rangle$ for each qubit. Alternatively, you could do an X-rotation with angle $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ like this $|i\rangle = \exp( i \frac{\pi}{4} X)|0\rangle$.
I cannot give you an application of this in an algorithm as I have never seen the state $|i\rangle^{\otimes n}$ in an algorithm. The Quantum Fourier Transform maps computational basis states to product states where each qubit lies on the equator of the Bloch sphere. The $H$ gate maps the equator of the Bloch sphere to the longitude circle going through $|0\rangle$, $|i\rangle$, $1\rangle$ and $-i\rangle$. Maybe it is worth experimenting around with that.
